# Знакомство с Hibernate для Java.Как внести в базу свою сущность? Выдаётся NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, hibernate

Всем доброго времени суток. Знакомлюсь с Hibernate.Решил сразу конфигурировать с помощью аннотаций. Но не получается, ловлю вот такое исключение:

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: namingStrategy
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.reset(AnnotationConfiguration.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<init>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:96)
    at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    ... 1 more*
```

**Вот мой код, где что-то ломается.**

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;


public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**А также вот структура проекта:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

**UPD. Класс UsersEntity**

```
package user;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "databs")
public class UsersEntity implements Serializable{
private String secondname;
private String firstname;
private int id;

@Basic
@Column(name = "secondname")
public String getSecondname() {
    return secondname;
}

public void setSecondname(String secondname) {
    this.secondname = secondname;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "firstname")
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    UsersEntity that = (UsersEntity) o;

    if (id != that.id) return false;
    if (secondname != null ? !secondname.equals(that.secondname) : that.secondname != null) return false;
    if (firstname != null ? !firstname.equals(that.firstname) : that.firstname != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = secondname != null ? secondname.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (firstname != null ? firstname.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + id;
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `AnnotationConfiguration` на `Configuration`

Comment: Тогда, на сколько я понимаю, надо всё менять и в hibernate.cfg.xml , это ж уже получается работа через xml.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное в классе UsersEntity нужно аннотировать поля класса, а не геттеры.
Примерно так:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
Integer id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Просто поменяйте Annotation configuration на Configuration и будет вам счастье. AnnonationConfiguration было убрано в версиях Hibernate

Comment: Добавил класс UsersEntity в вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста.